# Spring form doesn't accept Lombok annotations

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, lombok

I have a Student class in my project with Lombok annotations:

```
package com.sviero.chd;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

public class Student {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String firstName;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String lastName;

    public Student() {
    }
}
```

and another file `student-form.jsp` which uses Student's fields:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Student form</title>
</head>

<body>

<form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="student">
    First name: <form:input path="firstName"/>
    Last name: <form:input path="lastName"/>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that *form* tag can't resolve *firstName* and *lastName* getters and setters. It tells me to create setter and getter for these fields. It doesn't see Lombok annotations. It works when I generate usual getters and setters, but I would like to use Lombok annotations to have more readable class. Are standard getters/setters only way or is there a way to combine Lombok with this JSP file?

Comment: How do you compile the application? Does the Lombok annotation processor run? Note that no code at runtime will ever see your annotations, they are compile time-only.